# Confusing connection between negation logic with arbitrary data, vs logic with numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

[image]

so why is the negation of 2, -2 instead of just not 2?

Answer (score 2):

Because negation for statements is really not the same as negation for numbers.

When you negate a statement, you get another a statement.

When you negate a number, you get another number.

So these are two different operations, performed on two different sorts of objects.

Indeed, 'not 2' is meaningless ... now you're trying to apply the first kind of negation to the second kind of object. In fact, when you label '2' with 'q', you are already trying to treat '2' as a statement ... which it is not.